# Python cannot find specified folder

Tags: python

I have a folder within my Python project folder that contains around 400 images. I'd like to be able to write a Python script that can access the folder and then pull all of the filenames and print them to the console.

I have the below code, but when I run it I get the error message `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '/images/'`

What do I need to do to fix this? The folder name and `os.chdir()` parameters are correct.

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/images/")
for file in glob.glob("*.png"):
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have the leading slash.  That indicates you want a directory `images` in the root directory.  Change `"/images/"` to `"images/"`.

Comment: @Ramesh Yes.  If your `images` directory were one level above your project.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Thanks